# How can you search meta-data tags in Media Wiki / Wikipedia?

Tags: search, wikipedia, mediawiki

I'm not sure if meta-data tags / name-value pairs is what I'm referring to or not, but I'd like to be able to search Wikipedia's sidebar tags such as the ones displayed in the screenshot below:

[image: Example Wikipedia sidebar with name-value pairs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Wikipedia*, the information from infoboxes is often retrieved from *WikiData*. It can be queried [there](https://query.wikidata.org/).

If you have your own installation of *MediaWiki*, you can install *Semantic MediaWiki* and enrich your infobox templates with semantic annotations. After that, you can make [semantic queries](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Semantic_search) against the pages with those templates.

Comment: Isn't https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_tutorial a better place to start?